# Query to MultiDimensional Json with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysql-5.6

Well I have a Mysql query that output like this the example below.

I need to convert this data into Json without repeating the names, dates and pruchase_id when they are the same

Sample Query:

```
Name        Date        Purchase_ID Product_id  Product_Qtty

Jane        2020-02-05  1523        12563       9
Jane        2020-02-05  1523        3474        1
Jane        2020-02-05  1523        66634       4

Jane        2020-03-22  5320        34374       1
Jane        2020-03-22  5320        1234        3

Jane        2020-06-15  6893        12634       4
Jane        2020-06-15  6893        13004       1

Paul        2020-02-12  1523        10560       2
Paul        2020-02-12  1523        4454        8
Paul        2020-02-12  1523        66634       7

Paul        2020-03-21  5320        4475        2
Paul        2020-03-21  5320        4563        4
```

The Expected Json is not a simple json where each row in the table is an object or array inside the json,
I need that the repeated fields like "Jane" became a Key Level for all that rows that start with "Jane":

```
{
  "user":[
     {
        "name":"Jane",
        "purchases":[
          {
              "Purchase_ID": 1523,
              "products":[{
                            "product_id":12563,
                            "product_qtty":9
                          },{
                            "product_id":3474,
                            "product_qtty":1
                          },{
                            "product_id":66634,
                            "product_qtty":4
                          }
                        ]
            },{
              "Purchase_ID": 5320,
              "products":[{
                            "product_id":3474,
                            "product_qtty":1
                          },{
                            "product_id":1234,
                            "product_qtty":3
                          }
                        ]
            }

                    ]} // "... and etc"
]}
```

Update My code:

```
<?php

require_once("includes/db_connect.php");


$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME);


 $query = "SELECT * from User_sales";
 
$sth = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: What happened to the date in your required output

Answer (score 0):

If your table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_sales (name varchar(10), `date` date, Purchase_ID int, Product_id int, Product_Qty int);

INSERT INTO user_sales VALUES

('Jane','2020-02-05',  1523,        12563,       9),
('Jane','2020-02-05',  1523,        3474 ,       1),
('Jane','2020-02-05',  1523,        66634,       4),

('Jane','2020-03-22',  5320,        34374 ,      1),
('Jane','2020-03-22',  5320,        1234  ,      3),

('Jane','2020-06-15',  6893,        12634,       4),
('Jane','2020-06-15',  6893,        13004,       1),

('Paul','2020-02-12',  1523,        10560,       2),
('Paul','2020-02-12',  1523,        4454 ,       8),
('Paul','2020-02-12',  1523,        66634,       7),

('Paul','2020-03-21',  5320,        4475 ,       2),
('Paul','2020-03-21',  5320,        4563 ,       4);
```

And you do this:

```
SELECT 
   u2.`name`,
   u2.`Purchase_ID`, 
   JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT( 'product_id', u1.`Product_Id`, 'product_qty', u1.`Product_Qty`)) as `products`
FROM user_sales u1
INNER JOIN user_sales u2 ON u1.`name`=u2.`name` and u1.`Purchase_ID`=u2.`Purchase_ID`
GROUP BY u2.`name`, u2.`Purchase_ID`
```

The output will be:

```
+ --------- + ---------------- + ------------- +
| name      | Purchase_ID      | products      |
+ --------- + ---------------- + ------------- +
| Jane      | 1523             | [{"product_id": 12563, "product_qty": 9}, {"product_id": 3474, "product_qty": 1}, {"product_id": 66634, "product_qty": 4}, {"product_id": 12563, "product_qty": 9}, {"product_id": 3474, "product_qty": 1}, {"product_id": 66634, "product_qty": 4}, {"product_id": 12563, "product_qty": 9}, {"product_id": 3474, "product_qty": 1}, {"product_id": 66634, "product_qty": 4}] |
| Jane      | 5320             | [{"product_id": 34374, "product_qty": 1}, {"product_id": 1234, "product_qty": 3}, {"product_id": 34374, "product_qty": 1}, {"product_id": 1234, "product_qty": 3}] |
| Jane      | 6893             | [{"product_id": 12634, "product_qty": 4}, {"product_id": 13004, "product_qty": 1}, {"product_id": 12634, "product_qty": 4}, {"product_id": 13004, "product_qty": 1}] |
| Paul      | 1523             | [{"product_id": 10560, "product_qty": 2}, {"product_id": 4454, "product_qty": 8}, {"product_id": 66634, "product_qty": 7}, {"product_id": 10560, "product_qty": 2}, {"product_id": 4454, "product_qty": 8}, {"product_id": 66634, "product_qty": 7}, {"product_id": 10560, "product_qty": 2}, {"product_id": 4454, "product_qty": 8}, {"product_id": 66634, "product_qty": 7}] |
| Paul      | 5320             | [{"product_id": 4475, "product_qty": 2}, {"product_id": 4563, "product_qty": 4}, {"product_id": 4475, "product_qty": 2}, {"product_id": 4563, "product_qty": 4}] |
+ --------- + ---------------- + ------------- +
```

After this it should not be tooo complex to extend this another level, ( which I leave to you to be done.)

P.S. This was tested with MySQL 8.0

Comment: great, but Im stucked wit MySql 5.6